# How to make a web app for simple python text processing

Tags: python, web-applications, nltk

I have made a python program which does some text processing to whatever input I give and for now run I it simply by our terminal window(cmd). But now we want to make a simple web app which takes the input from user and then my application processes it and then the result is shown to user. Something like http://textanalysisonline.com/simple-text-summarizer.

As i am new to all this any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking into using Django - A framework for making python (web) applications.

I would look into downloading the python IDE [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) as it makes Django development quite easy and then look into some tutorials on how to make Django applications.

then I would install [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) and then follow the tutorials (maybe start [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/)) for figuring out how to add your script to a Django application. Happy coding!